# Задачка на графы про города и деревни

Tags: алгоритм, графы, поиск-пути

В стране есть **k** городов и **n** деревень, причём между городами нет прямых дорог, т.е. Нет такой дороги которая ведет из города в город. В этой стране есть **m** однонаправленных дорог с заданными длинами.
Гарантируется, что соответствующий граф ацикличен. Мне нужно оставить некоторое подмножество рёбер, так чтобы из любого города можно было добраться в любую деревню (новые дороги строить нельзя). Мне нужно найти минимальный суммарный вес выбранных дорог за **O(k + n + m + n log k)**.

Comment: @Кара Это задача о минимальном остове. Решается алгоритмом Крускала. Также для полного понимания этого алгоритма вам может понадобиться изучить структуру данных DSU (Система непересекающихся множеств).

Comment: Можете пояснить как в этой задаче использовать алгоритм Краскала, если он используется для неориентированного графа?...

Comment: @Кара действительно, невнимательно прочитал условие. Ну тогда я разве что слышал про алгоритм Чу-Лью/Эдмондса.